# How to execute an Ant target task in build.gradle?

Tags: android, ant, gradle, build.gradle

How can I get the task associated with an Ant target to execute from within the `build.gradle` file?

The part in `build.gradle` which imports the `build.xm`l file:

```
def targetSdk = android.defaultConfig.targetSdkVersion.getApiLevel()
ant.properties['android.version'] = "android-$targetSdk"
ant.properties['sdk-location'] = SDK_DIR
ant.importBuild(rootDir.absolutePath + "/bcproj/build.xml")
```

The ant target I want to execute is named `compile-android`. It successfully runs at the command line with:

```
./gradlew compile-android
```

But I'd like to include this in `build.gradle` so I can specify which ant target needs compiling for each buildType. In all my googling, all I could find references for is getting it to compile at the command line.

**Update 1**

I've tried adding the `compile-android` task as a dependency to another task that gets executed along with the build process. Though conceptually the two are really independent of each other. This still failed in getting `compile-android` to execute.

```
task copyShopMetadata(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'compile-android') {
    workingDir rootDir
    commandLine './copy_shop_metadata.sh'
}

copyShopMetadata.execute()
```

I've tried reversing the dependency, still doesn't work.

```
Task t = tasks.findByName('compile-android')
t.dependsOn(copyShopMetadata)
copyShopMetadata.execute()
```

**Update 2**

I should note that adding the dependency examples above does work when executing from the command line. However my end goal here is to be able to hit "sync project with gradle files" in Android Studio and have the the `compile-android` ant target compile.  Perhaps this just isn't possible?

Comment: You've got this reversed. You need "compile-android" to depend on your task, not the other way around, assuming you need your task to execute before "compile-android".

Comment: Still didn't work.  Updated my answer with what I tried.  Note, it does not matter if the task or "compile-android" goes first.

Comment: Manually executing a task from within the build script never makes sense. You have to start with the task run from the command line and manage your dependencies based on that.

Comment: The merits of executing a task in a build script is probably diverging from this question but I'd appreciate any links you have to explain that.  I'm still new to gradle.  However I am assuming it's no different then providing dependencies which say compile this module, compile this AAR, or compile this jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like the problem was a misunderstanding on my part for what the "*Sync Project with Gradle*" button was doing.  It is not the equivalent of executing a build from the command line.  It's not until I actually hit the run button in Android Studio does it perform the `compile-android` task. As hitting the run button is what's equivalent to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your task is not intended to be independent of all other processing, you're going to want your task to be depended on by some other task, which means that when you try to run that other task, your task will be executed first.  That task might be "build" for instance, so you might do something like this:

```
project.build.dependsOn("compile-android")
```

(I'm not certain of the exact syntax for this.)

Comment: I do have some other tasks executing during the build process.  I tried attaching `compile-android` with `dependsOn` on one of them and it still failed to build.  Updated question with the code tried with.